# MSAccess 2010 Linked Table from Sharepoint lookup Values Issue

Tags: vba, ms-access, sharepoint, sql-server-2016

i have a question which i couldn´t solve with other Threads.
My Situation:
I Need to load a SharePoint list into an SQL Server 2016, I dont have Access to SSIS, so I tried using MS Access.

I Created a linked table in Access and then inserted the SharePoint list with a query to my SQL Server. This works fine but only for columns which are not lookup columns. For the Lookup columns i only get the ID (instead of the Text).

I also read in some threads that I could create a SharePoint Workflow to create a calculated column with text instead of the ID. Unfortunately I dont have the rights to do this in SharePoint.

My next idea was to just create a local MS Access Table from SharePoint, because in this case MS Access gets the Text instead of the ID. But now im not sure how to refresh the data in my local Table automaticly with a macro or vba.

Are there any ideas how I would be able to insert SharePoints Lists  into SQL Server(preferably over MS Access)

Kind Regards
Johann

Answer (score 0):

Found a Solution working for me with the ImportSharePointList Macro Action.
Think this Feature is added in MS Access 2007